# How to find videos I haven't watched on a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to find YouTube videos for a specific channel that I haven't watched and/or rated yet? The red bottom border on videos are an indication, but they do not apply to videos watched a long time ago, and they don't show up if I've watched offline (via `youtube-dl`) and then voted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since nobody on the internet seems to have done that, I've decided to write a little script that removes all videos that have that red marker on the bottom on YouTube. I know that wasn't exactly what you wanted in your question, but it's still better than nothing.

First, you must be on the playlist view of all the uploads from that youtube channel. That's because if you just go to the "videos" tab it will only show up to about 300 videos, so you need the playlist view to show them all. To go to that:

- Go into any video of the channel you want
- Click on the channel name. That will give you a URL that looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdJvdDjXmRwt9ACt9EH8pnw
- Go to https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list= and add the ID from the channel URL.
- Before you enter, change the "UC" from the start of the ID to "UU". That way, you will have something like this: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUdJvdDjXmRwt9ACt9EH8pnw
- There you go!

From there you can access the developer tools of your browser and paste the code in this link into the console:

https://pastebin.com/krQv7atV

Alternatively, you can use this one if you using the new youtube design:

https://pastebin.com/UspkZxxz

That will scroll down and delete all of the watched videos automatically until it reaches the end of the channel. It will also remove all those annoying "playlist links" that playlists have (that is, it won't just to the next video when you finish watching the current one).

Well, that's it. Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Dang, that's some dedication!

Comment: You can use browser extension like tempermonkey for chrome and automate the script execution if you want.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added another script that works with the new design too.

Comment: Good stuff guy.

Comment: I am a complete JavaScript noob, but I think I got the code to work as a bookmarklet: [URI-Encoded](https://pastebin.com/uSWsmaiQ) [Cleartext version](https://pastebin.com/kQpjgwyi)

Comment: couldnt get it working

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know if you have already watched the video is if the red bar at the bottom of the thumbnail is all the way across. There is no specific section that you can go to where it is all videos that you haven’t watched.